# Error 429 Too many requests - telegram bot api

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня бот с кнопками, и если много раз нажимать на них, не дожидаясь ответа, - он слетает и выдает `Error 429 Too many requests`. 
Я попробовала решить проблему с помощью `global rate limiter` - ограничивать количество сообщений в секунду. Но ошибка все равно возникает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли еще как-то решить эту проблему? Использую библиотеку `Telebot, bot.polling`

Comment: Это ошибка со стороны HTTP. Может быть можно блокировать нажатие кнопки по ответ не придет (не знаю возможно ли это, давно не работал с ботами)? 429 Too Many Requests — клиент попытался отправить слишком много запросов за короткое время, что может указывать, например, на попытку DDoS-атаки. Может сопровождаться заголовком Retry-After, указывающим, через какое время можно повторить запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить в обработку `time.sleep(2)` - усыпить функцию после нажатия на кнопку на 2 сек, а вообще почитайте сколько запросов можно отправлять в определенный отрезок времени, и сделайте обработчик, который будет вызываться при каждом обращении и смотреть, когда был последний запрос к апи и можно ли спрашивать сейчас

Answer (score 0):

Простите, но можно из игр стянуть замечательную идею global cooldown.
В начале функции(которая вызывается при нажатии кнопки)дописать

```
global gcd
if gcd==1: return
gcd=1
Дальше ваши запросы
Пришёл ответ и gcd=0
```